# How can I interface, received HC-12 data and transmit the received data using sx-1278 RF-module in arduino-UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, rf, hc-12

I am currently working on a project, where I need to send data from first unit to the second unit which is a few km apart, so I decided to go with **hc-12 RF module** as it covers upto 5km. Then the data received in the second unit is again to be transmitted to the last unit which is several km apart from each other, so I decided to go with **sx-1278 RF module** which can easily transmit data up to 30kms. I am trying to get the received data to print on the serial monitor. So, **how do I transmit the received HC-12 data in the second unit using the sx-1278 RF module to the third unit? Is this operation even possible? Are these two boards compatible with each other?**

If the answer is yes, please do help me out with the coding part on how to interface these two RF-modules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of I/O do the two RF modules use?

Comment: For the input parts, I am using a temp sensor (LM-35), a pulse senor (RC-A-4015), and a GPS sensor (neo-6m) and for the output part, as of now, I'm just trying to print it on the serial monitor.

Comment: i asked about the RF modules ... let me rephrase that ... how do the RF modules communicate with an arduino?

Comment: The RF module consists of a 433 MHz RF transmitter and receiver modules. These are ASK or FSK type RF modules....The transmitter and receiver are needed to be interfaced with arduino for data transfer...The data is sent serially from the transmitter and is received by the receiver on the other end... the RF transmitter receives serial data from arduino and transmits it to the receiver through an antenna connected to the transmitter. The receiver receives the data through an antenna and gives the data to the microcontroller connected to it.

Comment: i did not ask how the RF modules communicate with other RF modules

Comment: I have used the digital pins of the Arduino...i.e.(4,5) ..as the transmitter and the receiver part of the RF module.

Comment: is it I2C? ....

Comment: No....its UART.

Comment: the one in the middle will have to use at least one hardware serial ... an arduino cannot use two software serial ports

Comment: oh..ohk. But is there any other way to send the data? or should I simply use an other arduino to perform this operation...by this I mean...collect the data received from hc-12 and store it in some storage device, and then send the data that is there on the storage device using sx-1278? is this method efficient? Or is there any other method to do this work? Please suggest.

Comment: it is unclear how data collection relates to the transmission of data ... the two functions are not really related ... you have three arduinos ... connect the RF module to software serial at the endpoint arduinos ... at the middle arduino, connect one RF module to software serial and the second one to the hardware serial

Comment: Ohk..I get it now. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: it may be possible to run without an arduino in the middle ... just connect the RF module data pins together

Comment: is that so?...I'll try that out then....One more thing, instead of using the hardware serial..could I just stick with two two software serial? Please check out this link where it demonstrates..on how to use to software serial .. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/TwoPortReceive

Comment: if you can make it work, then go for it

Comment: Ohk...Thank you so much for the help.